# Facebook Messenger send Message to individual, from outside of Messenger App

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messages

I have the following requirement and wonder if it is at all possible.

I want to create an app, webhook, or Python app that sends a simple message to a single Facebook Messenger user.

For example, when on a device without Facebook or Messenger (but internet enabled), trigger an event that sends a simple message to my partner.

So, use case... As a smartwatch wearer, I can send a message to my partner's Facebook messenger id without access to Facebook or Messenger applications.

Is this at all possible, and do you have any thoughts on how?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I never did that, but i guess this will help you [facebook send-api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/) This seems to be the offical documentation.

Comment: The messenger API is only for communication between a user and a page, so you would have to set up a page at least. But there are also limitations, on how often and how long a page can message a user via API, before the user needs to respond back to keep the conversation alive. Plus, you will probably have to go through the whole app review process, even if you and your partner would be the only ones using the app.

Comment: Ok thankyou CBroe....have started to read something about it expiring. Have set up a page, and got the token and an example python script, which returns an error 400 from FB. 
So Im starting to get into a rabbit hole probably too deep for my understanding.
I'll keep reading and will take into account what you've said, so thankyou again. Much appreciated.